# Cannot enter mysql shell with user in windows

Tags: mysql-cli

Username : mohit

> mysql -u mohit -h localhost -p

While I am trying to enter username mohit in my mysql shell in windows with/wo sudo prefix
it is going to next line as

> 

Entering passowrd does not work

Comment: must have got an error, which was it. Have you installed the latest version?

Comment: No errors displayed .But when i enter my  shell with user name  it navigates to the next line for password after entering password it again navigates to the next line.

Comment: the mysql shell acts differently, add a semicolon + return and write SELECT version(); return

Comment: Sorry but I cannot understand the literals of your sentence .Can you pls rewrite the cmd for entering into sql

Comment: you said that it goes to an empty row, that jmeasn that you are **in** the mysql shell and can use comands https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-commands.html

Comment: Yeah got this now !